# How do we call the style of a word/sentence with series of underscore?

Tags: single-word-requests

In Computer Programming, the programmer most often declare a variable or function with series of underscores.For instance,

- english_dot_stack_exchange.

Is there a style name for that kind of sentences/words with series of underscores/understrike/low line/low dash?

**EDIT:**

I would like to know the style's name.Just like **camelCase**.

Comment: If you're asking for a name for the style (`using_underscores` as opposed to `camelCase`), Wikipedia calls it *underscore-based* (Wikipedia, "CamelCase," under "History->Computer Programming->The 'Lazy Programmer' theory")

Comment: Let me ask you(person who downvoted this qn) one thing.Can you provide some reason,Why does this question is not useful?

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: I have not downvoted the question, but I guess it boils down to [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-python-a-snake-or-a-programming-language-if-the-latter-why-is-it-choking-my). I personally don't feel this question as off-topic, but I guess non-programmers may feel that way.

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want a generic name for the sentences/words with underscores themselves, or do you want a name for such a *style* of naming?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner,style of naming..just like camelCase..

Comment: @VijinPaulraj: I would recommend you clarify that in your question, as it has led to some confusion.

Comment: I didn't vote to close - after all, if OP had asked for a name for *ThisOrthographicStyle*, that would surely have been on-topic and would have had a single definitive answer. It's just OP's bad luck that apparently *this_orthographic_style* doesn't really have a standard name.

Comment: I always call the underscored version the “legible” form.

Answer (score 4):

Name you're looking for is [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). - Wikipedia

> Snake case (or snake_case) is the practice of writing compound words or phrases in which the elements are separated with one underscore character (_) and no spaces, with each element's initial letter usually lowercased within the compound and the first letter either upper or lower case—as in "foo_bar" and "Hello_world".

Answer (score 0):

I had a CS teacher who called them *engineer's spaces*, but I doubt that it was common usage. [Stroustrup](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#Hungarian) just calls them, "underscores to separate words in an identifier." I feel like if there were a common name, he would know about it and use it, so wikipedia's *underscore-based* is probably the best you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and can research in 5 minutes, there isn't even a concise term for it in the computing world where it's still common in certain programming languages; it's just a "lowercase underscored identifier". You might hear of it as "Hungarian notation", but that term relates almost exclusively to the identification of the type and scope of a variable identifier in the name of the identifier itself; "li_local_integer" is Hungarian notation but so is "lintLocalInteger".

The use, obviously, is to avoid whitespace, which is in many languages a de facto division between code elements (keywords, identifiers, sometimes operators). While "camelCasing" and "PascalCasing" as conventions for similar situations have the eponymous terms, there isn't a single catchy term for identifiers that use underscores.

Perhaps "lower_score", "Cap_Score" and "UPPER_SCORE" could be introduced, but as the use of underscores to separate identifiers in actual code is a deprecated style in most of the popular languages, it's unlikely to catch on.

Comment: Deprecated?! What about Python, and I think javascript and Ruby?

Answer (score -1):

If you want a *name* for the style of "sentences/words with series of underscores/understrike/low line/low dash", I'd go with "underscored", as I've heard that in use.

Example:

> Please make sure all database tables are named in an underscored fashion.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvoting on these answers?

Comment: I can't explain it. A string of words joined by underscores has no meaning in standard English - it's just something encouraged by programming languages. So I don't see how you can call it anything other than a *symbol* (or perhaps, *identifier*, but that won't be correct in all contexts). Cornbread's *CamelCase* is an interesting digression, but this looks like the only plausible "answer" to me.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: he is asking for the name of a specific style in naming variables in programming. `symbol`, although not wrong is not a specific name for that style, as it also applies to the *camelCased* version of the variable's name (and to any other style).

Comment: @nico: It's not entirely clear to me if the OP is asking for a term for "sentences/words with series of underscores/understrike/low line/low dash" or a term that refers to the *style* of such sentences/words, but the first interpretation seemed most likely to me.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I would propend for the second, otherwise I agree that the question would be pointless.